# What could be causing NaN to appear when using parseFloat to calculate tax totals?

Tags: forms, nan

We're working on a digital form and we keep getting the NaN return on this.

```
room = parseFloat(data.RoomTax1);
resort = parseFloat(data.ResortFeeTax);
baggage = parseFloat(data.BaggageTax);
total = 0.00;
total = room + resort + baggage;
value = parseFloat(total);
```

Is there something we are missing?

We've been stuck on this for about 2 months. Im not sure if this has somthing to do with the total= 0.00;